# How to align UICollectionViewCells from left to right?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I should design UICollectionView like below image.

[image]

It was almost done. but my UICollectionView is displaying like below image.

[image]

I thought it would be solved if I set `semanticContentAttribute` of UICollectionView to `forceLeftToRight`. but the result was not changed.

How can I design that like first image?

Comment: Set constraints.

Comment: `forceLeftToRight` simply forces a left to right layout even when the locale is a right to left locale. The complicated way to do what you want is to subclass the flow layout class and override `layoutElementsForItem(at:)`. The simpler way is to add an additional invisble/empty cell in the case where there is an odd number of cells.

Comment: @Paulw11I think this should be the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forceLeftToRight` simply forces a left to right layout even when the locale is a right to left locale, so this doesn't help since `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` centers the cells within its view.

The complicated way to do what you want is to subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and override `layoutElementsForItem(at:)` to place the last cell on the left.

The simpler way is to add an additional invisble/empty cell in the case where there is an odd number of cells.